# Creating a list of files, removing "duplicates" with different suffix

Tags: shell, shell-script, files, filenames

I have a problem that (I think) require a bit of script-magic - not sure what would be best though...

I have one directory with lots pictures in different formats - jpg, gif, png, tiff and svg.

*Some* (not all!) of the png-and svg-files are in pairs - ie. one png and one svg version of the same image, both with the same filename, except that the suffix differs (eg. figleaf.png and figleaf.svg).

I need a script that will take the file-list (made by `ls`), and remove the svg-version of all twins, leaving just the png-version.  All other files (non twins) - including svg-files without a png-twin - should remain in the list (together with the png-version of the twins).  Alternatively, a script that creates a list of all svg-files with a corresponding png-twin.

I think some of twins may have slight difference in between the versions - eg. figleaf.png and FigLeaf.svg - so it would be great if the script could be *optionally* changed to ignore the case of the letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it using bash/ksh :

```
for i in *.svg; do test -e "${i%.*}.png" && rm "$i"; done
```

Or, formatted differently :

```
for i in *.svg; do
    test -e "${i%.*}.png" && rm "$i"
done
```

Replace the `rm` with `echo` to test before doing the actual deleting.

**EDIT :**

sputnick just edited a solution very similar to this in his answer, you should take his as he was the first to answer.

Comment: @sputnick Yes, I saw your edit after I posted my answer. Just edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

(remove the `i` modifier in the substitution if you want to be case sensitive)

```
$ perl -e '
    foreach my $file (<*.png>) {
       ($ext_free = $file) =~ s/\.png//i;
       unlink "$ext_free.svg" if -e "$ext_free.svg";
    }
' *.[Pp][Nn][Gg]
```

To try it before, put a `print` instead of `unlink`.

or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
shopt -s nocaseglob # case insensitive
# use 'shopt -u nocaseglob' for case sensitive
for file in *.png; do
    [[ -e ${file%.png}.svg ]] && rm -f "${file%.png}.svg"
done
```